# How to specify localhost as the server name in t-sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am dynamically connecting to different database servers and databases in some select code. However when I'm testing, I do it all using a local machine server.

Is there anyway to explicitly specify 'LOCALHOST' as the server name in T-SQL code? A bit like this:

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
 [LOCALHOST].[DBName].[Schema].[TableName]
```

The reason it has to be in there is because the value is coming dynamically from a table. For testing purposes I just want to set it all to point to the local machine.

However, if I put the actual name of the local machine server in there e.g. PHILS-PC then if I move to a different development machine with its own local copy of SQL Server, I'd have to update all the tables to use the name of that local server. I thought LOCALHOST took care of that but it doesn't work in T-SQL code. I get this error:

> Could not find server 'LOCALHOST' in sys.servers. Verify that the
>   correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored
>   procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Comment: What do you get if you run `select * from sys.servers`?

Comment: Actually the answer is right there: `If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers`

Comment: So I add localhost as a server back to itself?

Comment: @kaybee99 I get the name of the actual local machine. So something like "John-PC" depending on which laptop I use

Comment: Where are these query are executed? on SSMS, SQLCMD or other applications?

Comment: @volumeone so what happens if you substitute "John-PC" in place of `LOCALHOST`?

Comment: @keybee99 it works fine then. but I use different machines, hence I can't have JOHN-PC as the servername in my tables. I'd have to update all the tables everytime I switch machine.

Comment: Use table names without servername

Comment: @qxg its executed in a SP within SSMS

Answer (score 0):

No you dont have to mention localhost. Localhost context is decided when you initially connect to a sql server. Whether it may be SSMS or application code once you establish a connection t sql server , it is considered to be your localhost.

Then from there any code executed is executed on the server you established the connection to, which is localhost for that query and for any cross server queries you will have to use a linked server query with

`FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[Schema].[table]`

Moral of the story, you will not mention Localhost in your queries because it is understood you can only execute sql code once you have connected to a server, then whatever you do there is done in the context of localhost which obviously makes sense.

Comment: The ServerName is stored in a table for each of my clients. In the production code it will connect to their servers. For testing, I need to use LocalHost as a placeholder for their actual Server Name because I keep a copy of their database in my local machine's server (i.e. the test server)